# Create a new account and Login to an account

Tags: python, function

Can I ask how to ask a user to create a new account if he or she is a first-time user whereby ask a user to log in if he or she is not a first-time user?

```
#Register Swinburne Sarawak Account
print("Please register for a login account with Swinburne Sarawak.")
def RegisterAccount():
    while True:
        RegisterAccount = ""
        RegisterAccount = input("Are you a first time user of our online portal? ([Y]Yes/[N]No)")
        FirstTimeUser = RegisterAccount.upper()
        if FirstTimeUser == "Y":
            print("You will need to create your account as a new student.")
        elif FirstTimeUser == "N":
            print("User Already Exist. Please login as a returning user.")
        else:
             continue
        break

RegisterAccount()
```

Comment: Well, there are issues here.  You really shouldn't create a variable with the same name as your function.  Beyond that, this is a good start.  To make the user task easier, instead of requiring two responses, you might consider saying "Please enter your user name, or 'new' if you are a new user."  That way, existing users only have to answer once.

Comment: You'll have to decide how to store the existing usernames.  Text file?  Database?  There are many good choices.